# simple parse between function in R?

Tags: regex, r, html-parsing

Let's say I wanted to extract a string found between two defined strings. For example, the function,we'll call it `parse_between()` would work as follows in R:

```
>main_string<-"the quick brown fox>$ jumps over the lazy </ dog"
>substring<-parse_between(main_string, begin=">$", end="</")
>substring
[1] " jumps over the lazy "
```

Even better if it could produce a vector with elements corresponding to each instance. I've searched some of the packages available for string manipulation like "stringr" but have not found a function to do this as easily as the example shows. My motivation is to parse html files unfortunately despite searching I haven't found an html parser for R.

Comment: Did you have a look at the XML package? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html

Comment: Hmm I just assumed it was XML specific, it looks pertinant thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off,  read this question & answer very carefully:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Then, if still undeterred,  use `regex` or `gsub` , both of which have metacharacters specifying the beginning or end of a line.  What you could do then, is replace

```
{start_of_line through to ">$"}
```

with nothing, then replace

```
{"</" through to end_of_line}
```

with nothing.

Comment: Thought I could avoid actually learning regex but doesn't look like it. I guess it's good for me anyhow. Thanks for the laugh.

Comment: Ok so to delete the first part one would use `uptostring<-sub(x=main_string,pattern=".x",replace="")` and then the second would be somthing similar. this video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvHjYOilOf8) was very helpful in understanding regular expressions. Is there a way to say up to but not including a character or starting from but not including a character?

Comment: yes: basically you tell regex to start at beginning of the line ("$"), accept any characters (using "."  ) so long as they are not (for this example, want not to include a "K"  `$.[^K]`   If that doesn't work, blame me :-) and dig up a regex cheat sheet.